# Streetview from Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

Looks like this question hasn't been asked in a while...

Any way to get streetview from the Google Maps SDK for iOS?

I have a client who is specifically interested in the Google Maps Streetview feature for his app, but, like most clients, he really doesn't want the feature to require going outside of the app.  (This is where Android is one up on iOS, with their omnipresent back button.  Sigh.)
The need for streetview is driven by a clear benefit in this app to being able to see actual images of buildings, lots, etc. as opposed to the 3D satellite imagery in Apple Maps, which is cool but not well suited for this app's purposes, as the buildings, lots, etc. are distorted.

I combed through the documentation for the iOS Google Maps SDK, looking for a way to get streetview.

I also downloaded the SDK and ran through the demos.

No dice on either account.

I see that I can get to a streetview image using Google Street View Image API, which is better than nothing:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

Here is a sample call from the documentation:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false

But building something into the app to let the user modify things like the size (via zoom), heading, pitch, etc. sure feels like I would be "reinventing the wheel" and is something that would be available in an SDK...

Thanks!

Del

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps iOS SDK 1.4 (released a few hours ago) has this feature:

- [Street View in iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview)

Comment: That's crazy timing...  But if only every software company would respond to my questions like that... snicker.

Comment: Yes, crazy! I was waiting for this release, but it didn't solve my question :(... I'm glad it helped you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The best option currently available for accessing streetview from google maps ios sdk seems to be using the [Google Maps URL scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) which will call the official google maps app for iphone based on the values provided by the user from the custom maps app(using ios sdk). The input values that can be used with the url scheme include:

1, mapmode : here **streetview** option can be chosen to show the map in streetview mode

2, center : center latitude,longitude point for the map to be displayed

3, zoom

4, views

Comment: Thanks for the response but that would require leaving the app, which the client doesn't want.